# Migrate 1.9 to 2.2 when StoreView is not assigned to Store/Website

Tags: magento2, store-view, magento2-migration-tool, websites, data-migration-tool

So maybe someone have already experienced something like that and will be able to help me out here:

I have to migrate a 1.9 Magento to 2.2 which I do quite often in the last months and which is mostly not a big deal.

Unfortunately I have been confronted with a problem I never faced before:

In the 1.9 Shop (the shop has only 1 StoreView) the StoreView is not assigned to any Website or Store:
[image]

I realised that when I finished the migration to Magento 2, because in Magento 2 my products (although they all were in the backend) did not show up in the frontend. I therefore did some research and found out that for the products to be shown they have to be assigned to a storeview, a store and a website.

In 1.9 however, everything works perfectly, although no Store/Website exists.

Now in 2.2 I tried to create a new Website, and a new Store (since after the migration those also were missing in 2.2) and then assign my storeview to the Store. This ended up in an error 500 in both front- and backend.

Has anyone ever faced a problem like that? How can I make my products show in the frontend after the migration? How can I "recreate" a missing website/store?

Answer (score 0):

Well actually this had nothing at all to do with the `StoreViews`.

I just had to `reindex` and then clean cache and deploy... simple as that...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation. - [From Review](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/113420)